# What the common examples of $E=mc^2$?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

this theory say's mass convert into energy and energy convert in to mass 
Whats he example of energy convert into mass?

Comment: These videos might answer pretty well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xo232kyTsO0 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ztc6QPNUqls

Comment: According to the article ['Einstein Was Right: You Can Turn Energy Into Matter'](http://www.forbes.com/sites/paulrodgers/2014/05/19/einstein-was-right-you-can-turn-energy-into-matter/) there is a proposed experiment to turn energy into matter by colliding photons, an interaction that will generate electrons and positrons. However, we have to wait and see the results. Same article published on MAY 19, 2014 says "until now there has been no way to ... turn energy into matter.", It appears that nobody has ever converted energy into matter.

Comment: @Energizer777 *"It appears that nobody has ever converted energy into matter."* is a deeply incorrect statement. The thing about press-releases is that they are generally coached in the most dramatic language possible and fairly precise parsing of the claim is necessary to read through that, but it gets worse after a science writer has translated it for a lay audience because all the nuance gets lost and the result is often simply stupid from the point of view of an expert. Matter is unavoidably made from energy in every particle accelerator on the face of the planet.